# "When it comes to doing something" Are there alternatives?

Tags: formality, discourse-markers

Do you think "*When it comes to*" is a formal or informal expression?
I want to use this in the TOEFL writing paper.

Answer (score 4):

Informal. Use this.

```
Concerning ...
With regards to..
```

Comment: I want to say : People tend to make subjective decisions when it comes to traveling. How do you use "with regards to" for conveying this meaning?

Comment: Maybe try *about*.

Comment: Bib's 'about' is the least marked way to state this. 'When it comes to' is semantically equivalent, but has a varying degree of pragmatic flavour. It can be used as a topic-change marker (Although many people look at the hotel reviews before booking, when it comes to travelling, people tend to make subjective decisions.), or a 'crescendo-marker' (Many people say they are in favour of greener forms of energy, but when it comes to having to pay bills twice as big as before, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Aside from "with regard to," consider "[with respect to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+regard+to%2Cin+regard+to%2Cas+regards%2Cwith+respect+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20regard%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20regard%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20regards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20respect%20to%3B%2Cc0)."

> People tend to make subjective decisions with respect to traveling.